# Minimizing XAML App Startup Times

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Microsoft's article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994639.aspx) states that you can create an extended splash screen page during which you can create your MainPage and then navigate to it once loaded.

The only problem is that the Loaded event of a page will never trigger until the page to the the `Window.Current.Content` property.

Does anyone have a solution for this? - My MainPage has a fairly large amount of XAML and takes a while to load on lower end devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the app has a Frame control at its visual root. You can modify it for example by putting your own UserControl in there (I usually call it AppShell) which has the Frame used by all pages, you can have a layer for popups, log in screens etc. or the extended splash screen.

To solve your problem - just put both the Frame and the extended splash control in a Grid and only navigate to your first page after the extended splash control is loaded. Then everything else should be simple.

Comment: Sounds like a fantastic idea but I haven't implemented it (yet). The problem was due to await / async operators in the OnNavigatedTo event - for some reason there is an issue on how these are handled. I fixed it by running a new task - starting a new thread would work too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use MainPage analogously to a MasterPage in ASP.NET you MainPage should have the APP Bar definitions, and should ONLY contain a Single Frame Element in the Body. 
Using this pattern to set the content of the app instead of

```
Window.Current.Content = // An Application Page 
use
AppFrame.Content = //An Application Page
```

Consider also, removing your Mainpage code from the MainPage element and placing it in a Custom User control, then you can bubble up an event from the userControl for the MainPage to Handle. It will also allow you to uise that functionality in other places in the app without entirely re-creating the logic and UI.

Here is the Example XAML for MainPage:

>

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="CommonStyles" Source="/Common/StandardStyles.xaml" />
</Page.Resources>
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="NavigationAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0" AutomationProperties.Name="Global App Bar" >
        <Grid>                
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel x:Name="LeftCommands" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <!-- App Bar Buttons Removed --> 
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
```

Add a Public Property of Type Frame to the application View Model with a Getter and Setter

```
public Frame SelectedAppFrame {get;set;}
```

in the MainPage.xaml.cs file Assign an property:

```
ApplicationViewModel vm = this.PageBackgroundGrid.DataContext as ApplicationViewModel;
vm.SelectedAppFrame = this.AppFrame;
```

and the Code for generic Navigating In the App View Model is :

```
public void HandleNavigaitionEvent(object sender, string pageName, Frame AppFrame, StackPanel stack)
        {
            var content = Pages.Where(i => i.Name == pageName).FirstOrDefault();
            NavigateTrigger(AppFrame, content);
        }

public void NavigateTrigger(Frame AppFrame, LayoutAwarePage content)
        {
            EventAggregator.GetEvent<PageNavigatedEvent>().Publish(content);
            AppFrame.Content = content;
            NaviagationPath.Add(content);
        }
```

That way you can Propgate the changes into the AppFram from anywhere in your application the the ApplicationViewModel is accessible from (Which should be everywhere).